# Replace 2 step Regex with 1 step Regex to get one upper case letter between underscores

Tags: regex, vb.net

I have a string, myFile, that looks like: Name_2019-11-29_D_HPSeries.txt. I need to extract the letter D between the underscores...the letter could be any uppercase letter. Right now I am using a 2 step Regex code.

```
Dim bC As String = Regex.Match(myFile, "_[A-Z]+_").ToString
             boatClass = Regex.Match(bC, "[A-Z]+").ToString
```

This works but I believe it could be done with one line. I tried the code below but it doesn't work.

```
boatClass = Regex.Replace(myFile, "_[A-Z]_", "[A-Z]").ToString
```

Comment: ... or `Dim bC = myFile.Substring(myFile.LastIndexOf("_"c) - 1, 1)`

Comment: Works great. I was hoping to get an answer using substring. now I have two options...see Regex answer below. I didn't realize that the first index could be negative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use positive lookarounds to avoid a 2-step process, checking that the characters before and after the letter are underscores without capturing them:

```
Dim myFile AS String = "Name_2019-11-29_D_HPSeries.txt"
Dim bC As String = Regex.Match(myFile, "(?<=_)[A-Z](?=_)").ToString
Console.WriteLine(bc)
```

Output:

```
D
```

Comment: Thanks Nick, works great. Now I understand a little bit more about look ahead and look behind. I removed the + since I am looking for one uppercase letter only.

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there with a single char A-Z, but you could wrap it in a capturing group and then use the [Match.Groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups?view=netframework-4.8) property.

```
_([A-Z])_
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mHSbvo/1) | [VB.Net Demo](https://ideone.com/CBryzd)

For example

```
Dim myFile AS String = "Name_2019-11-29_D_HPSeries.txt"
Dim bC As String = Regex.Match(myFile, "_([A-Z])_").Groups(1).Value
Console.WriteLine(bc)
```

Result

```
D
```